# Remote image server is serving different file than the one accessed by getimagesize

Tags: php, image, remote-server

I have a site where I check image sizes in order to resize various HTML elements around them. The image URLs come in through data and are hosted remotely, so I don't know the image dimensions beforehand. I was using getimagesize and this seemed to be working OK (although slowly), but now I'm seeing a situation where the image dimensions I'm getting back from getimagesize aren't the dimensions of the image file that I actually end up getting. The image URL is not pointing directly to a file but is pointing to a script that serves up an image, so I'm assuming that somehow the image file being served is changing between the getimagesize check and the actual download.

Has anyone dealt with this issue? Are there any server-side solutions that would get the right dimensions, or would I need to go to a JS solution after the images have loaded?
Brian

Comment: I would recommend tuning your CSS so, that you won't have to deal with it in PHP or JS. Posting HTML code here would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a better approach not be to set up an image.onload, so that as soon as the image is loaded, you can grab the actual image size and adjust the page then?

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out. There were HTML entities in the image URL that were treated different ways by getimagesize and the actual download. However, given the slowness I've been getting with getimagesize, these are both good suggestions to look into. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the image file to a temporary file, and then call `getimagesize()` on the file.

Although according to one of the comments in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), that's essentially how `getimagesize($url)` works. So I'm not sure why you're getting different dimensions. If the image file is changing on the fly, there doesn't seem to be any way for your PHP script to get the size that the browser will see, so you'll have to use a solution in Javascript that runs after the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Image URL being passed in the data had HTML entities which were treated differently by getimagesize and with the actual image download.